# Interface Android Keystore from NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-keystore

**Introduction**

I am currently working on a solution that would use Android Keystore new features (since Marshmallow , API level 23).
My app use both Java and C++ (NDK) and I have some critical operation that needs to be perform from native code.

I am able to use properly the new Keystore from Java.

Unfortunately, the Android C++ sources are not documented and I have tried to look into it.

**Question**

I would like to perform operation from both Java and C++.
The only dynamic library that I could use and interface is the [IKeystoreService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/security/+/android-cts-6.0_r13/keystore/include/keystore/IKeystoreService.hhttp://) and with its associated library /system/lib/libkeystore_binder.so.

I have been able to include headers and the library and compile it.
But since the only connection point I can use is a Binder between Java and C++ IKeystoreService(s), I can't find which data I am supposed to use in order to achieve a simple AES encryption (for example).

Would anyone have any insight ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not

Comment: still no solution ?

Comment: I did not find a solution and I am not working on it anymore...